# Default value for function parameters in VB6

Tags: vb6, function-parameter

How to specify default value for a parameter in VB6?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
Private Sub SomeSub(Optional SomeParam As Integer = 0)
    ' blah
End Sub
```